# Fuse two csv files

Tags: bash, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to fuse two csv files this way using BASH.

files1.csv :

```
Col1;Col2
a;b
b:c
```

file2.csv

```
Col3;Col4
1;2
3;4
```

result.csv

```
Col1;Col2;Col3;Col4
a;b;0;0
b;c;0;0
0;0;1;2
0;0;3;4
```

The '0's in the result files are just empty cells.
I tried using paste command but it doesn't fuse it the way I want.

```
paste -d';' file1 file2
```

Is there a way to do it using BASH?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One in awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS=";" '
FNR==1  { a[1]=a[1] (a[1]==""?"":OFS) $0; next }    # mind headers
FNR==NR { a[NR]=$0 OFS 0 OFS 0; next }              # hash file1
        { a[NR]=0 OFS 0 OFS $0 }                    # hash file2
END     { for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(i in a)print a[i] }  # output
' file1 file2
Col1;Col2;Col3;Col4
a;b;0;0
b:c;0;0
0;0;1;2
0;0;3;4
```